# wxPython How to correctly close wxProgressDialog when set to Pulse()

Tags: wxpython

I have recently migrated an application from python2.7.15 (wx 3.0.2.0) to python 3.7.9 (wx 4.1.1)

The application uses a wx.ProgressDialog set to Pulse() while waiting for some tasks to complete
and then uses Destroy() to attempt to close the ProgressDialog window.

It runs without errors on Python27 but it crashes on Python37.
In both ProgressDialog.Destroy() does not actually seem to close the dialog box but it is closed when the next wx element is displayed.

```
import wx  
from time import sleep

def main():
    app = wx.App()

    progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Model Manager", "Connecting...")
    progress_dlg.Pulse()
    sleep(5)      # some long tasks are done here
    progress_dlg.Destroy()
    print("waiting")
    sleep(5)

    extracted_names = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
    CANDialog = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, "Please select:", "Selection", extracted_names)
    CANDialog.SetSelection(0)
    if CANDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        choosen_can = CANDialog.GetSelection()
    else:
        return
    print(extracted_names[choosen_can])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In python37 this gives the following error:

```
    if CANDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion ""wxEventLoopBase::GetActive() == m_tempEventLoop"" failed at ..\..\src\generic\progdlgg.cpp(718) in wxGenericProgressDialog::~wxGenericProgressDialog(): current event loop must not be changed during wxGenericProgressDialog lifetime
```

If I replace the Destroy() with Update() then the dialog is correctly closed automatically:

```
progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Model Manager", "Connecting...", maximum=1)
progress_dlg.Pulse()
sleep(5)
progress_dlg.Update(1)
```

Whilst I can solve my problem, I would like to understand if this is the right way to do it & why Destroy() is not working?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Gabbo CH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Destroy should be called on the ProgressDialog.
Update() with the maximum value is the right way. (With style PD_AUTO_HIDE, which is the default.)
Afterwards, delete the reference to the dialog. Best way is to use the context manager.

If you look at the wxPython demo and the wxWidgets C++ examples, there's no Show(), ShowModal() or Destroy().
Recently there was a related ticket for wxPython where I have also added a usage example.

https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1610#issuecomment-1090664834

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_generic_progress_dialog.html

Comment: As a new user I cannot give you an upvote, but thanks for the confirmation & useful references.

Comment: @GabboCH you may not be able to upvote but you can Accept the answer. I think you will see a green tick mark on the answer. Click that, if the answer did indeed answer the question to your satisfction. Upvotes are just a bonus really.

Answer (score 0):

As Dietmar pointed you in the right direction, I'll concentrate on the other issues.
You code doesn't create the wx `MainLoop` and you are not allowing for the gauge to be visually updated. While your code may freakishly work in that small code sample, there will be issues later on, when the code increases.

Here's your code with minor changes. It includes setting the MainLoop and falling back to that loop during the `long task` to allow the progress gauge to update.

```
import wx  
from time import sleep

def main():
    progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Model Manager", "Connecting...", maximum=100)
    for i in range(5):
        progress_dlg.Pulse()
        sleep(1)      # some long tasks are done here
        wx.GetApp().Yield()
    progress_dlg.Update(100)
    print("waiting")
    wx.GetApp().Yield()
    sleep(5)

    extracted_names = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
    CANDialog = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, "Please select:", "Selection", extracted_names)
    CANDialog.SetSelection(0)
    if CANDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        choosen_can = CANDialog.GetSelection()
    else:
        return
    print(extracted_names[choosen_can])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

See: https://docs.wxpython.org

Comment: Thanks Rolf. In my main application I do have the app.MainLoop(), I missed it from my code sample.
Although I have to admit I didnt really understand why I had it (the original application was created by someone else) so the explanation of why it is needed was helpful for me.

Comment: I have not tried this code. There could be problems with the `Yield` call.

From the wxWidgets documentation at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_generic_progress_dialog.html :

"Note that this becomes even more important if the dialog is instantiated during the program initialization, e.g. from wxApp::OnInit(): the dialog must be destroyed before the main event loop is started in this case."

...

Comment: ...


This is actually for `wxGenericProgressDialog` but should be followed also for the native version as this is not available on all platforms and so e.g. on macOS wx will fall back to the generic implementation.

Anyway, I don't see much use for a progress dialog in initalization code. Better do such tasks in a separate call via `wx.CallAfter`.

Comment: @DietmarSchwertberger This code sample is merely illustrative, with the "something happens here" tag. The `Yield` is simply to illustrate that you need to return to the `MainLoop` for the progress gauge to be seen to function. If "something happens here" was another thread, I would rely on an event to trigger an update.

Comment: thanks for the interesting discussion. In my application, it is running in a single thread & I want to wait for the long task before continuing (it is opening an external application) bofore continuing to connect to the application via win32com.
Therefore, I didn't add the "yield" command to return control to the main application.