# WxPython App/Frame Goes to Background after ProgressDialog is closed

Tags: wxpython

I have a wx application & use a ProgressDialog to inform the user when some tasks are running.
This worked fine in Python2.7 under windows 10.
I am now using Python 3.7.9 & wxPython 4.1.1 and I have a strange behaviour I do not understand.

When the progress dialog is closed, the main application window seems to drop to the background in windows (i.e. underneath Folders or applications which were open at the same time.).
E.g. If I run the application from PyCharm, once the ProgressDialog is closed, the wx window goes behind PyCharm.

To restore it to the foreground, I have to select it from the windows taskbar again.

How do I keep the wx application window in the same position as it was before?

With the following code I see the same behaviour but I do not understand what I am doing wrong? (or why it worked fine in python27).

```
import wx
import time

class Application(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):   
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(1050, 580))
        self.Show()

        self.progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Update", "Updating SVN Folders...", maximum=100)
        # Update SVN
        for ctr in range (5):
            self.progress_dlg.Update(ctr+1, "SVN Updating:...")
            time.sleep(1)

        self.progress_dlg.Update(100)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = Application(None, "SVN Update")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: works as expected on *nix: Python 3.10.4, wx python 4.4.1

Comment: There's always the frames `wx.STAY_ON_TOP` style, although that may be a little too drastic.

Comment: I've already tried STAY_ON_TOP and this works as intended but its not really what I want.
I use my app as a launcher with simple buttons to perform some tasks (SVN update or open applications).
When I open an application, I want that to be above the launcher.
I seem to have many "quirks" with wxPython and Python3.

Comment: Is this more about your IDE than wxpython i.e. do you see the same behaviour running the code from the command line. I notice that you don't `Destroy` the dialog e.g. `self.progress_dlg.Destroy()` does that help?

Comment: It is the same when I run it from the command line. therefore, I do not think it is caused by PyCharm.
The Destroy() doesnt make any different, the behaviour is still the same.
Actually, I removed ProgressDialog.Destroy() from all of my code based on a previous post on here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877268/wxpython-how-to-correctly-close-wxprogressdialog-when-set-to-pulse

Comment: I have run exactly the same code in Python 2.7.15, Python 3.7.9 & Python 3.9.
Python 27 works fine, both Python3 versions have the same.

It is strange that the application only goes back one level, not completely to the bottom.

As a workaround until I can understand why I have this problem, is there a way to make the application jump back to the foreground?

Comment: Try `self.SetFocus()`     A tip: when answering a comment from a specific person, start with the @ sign and the first few letters of their name. You will be given the option of using their full name. In this way that person is alerted that you have directed a comment at them. Otherwise it's down to chance, if they come back to an old question.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony SetFocus() doesnt work but self.Raise() does it........
But, only if it is immediately after the update of the ProgressDialog. If there is another task in between then the windows stays in the background.
<pre>        `# This works
        self.progress_dlg.Update(100)
        self.Raise()`

        `# This does not
        self.progress_dlg.Update(100)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.Raise()`
<\pre>

Comment: @GabboCH Huzzah! You cracked it! It might be worth raising it as a bug with the windows version of wxpython, as it's clearly wrong that you have to resort to that.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony thanks for your help.
I will pose the same question in the wxPython forum & see if this behaviour is already known.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony after some ideas from the wxPython forum I found a solution which I posted below.
I think there is perhaps still a bug with PD_APP_MODAL, Im waiting for an answer from the other forum & will follow-up with a bug-report if necessary.
Thanks for giving me the confidence that I wasnt doing something silly & to follow the topic further.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from Rolf & from the DiscussPython forum, this is my final tested solution using `parent=self` & keeping the default ProgressDialog styles:

```
import wx
import time

class Application(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.filename = "ModelManager.py"

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(1050, 580))
        self.Show()

        self.progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Update", "Updating SVN Folders...", parent=self, maximum=100)
        for ctr in range (5):
            self.progress_dlg.Update(ctr+1, "SVN Updating:...")
            time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(3)
        self.progress_dlg.Update(100)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = Application(None, "SVN Update")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is the thread from DiscussPython where the bug is reported for the default attribute parent=none:
https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/wxpython-app-frame-goes-to-background-after-progressdialog-is-closed/36022/17

Comment: this is the wxPython bug report:
https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2189

Comment: You are posting the same question on multiple platforms? That alone is bad style already. Not even reading the answers makes it even worse.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I have done wrong or which comment I have ignored?
I posted my question here first & after some discussion it was suggested I ask on DiscussPython if this was a known bug because the behaviour could not be explained.
Hence my question on the other site & the useful contribution from several people to find the same problem & raise a bug report.
As the discussion from DiscussPython helped me find a workaround for my problem, I thought it would be helpful to post an update of this solution here for anybody who came across my original post .....

Comment: & the people who initially helped me on this site.
Sorry if this is not concidered good practise :(

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion on discuss.wxpython.com I have found a good solution to my problem.

The problem seems to come from the ProgressDialog style wx.PD_APP_MODAL.
If I explicitly define the style as style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE so that PD_APP_MODAL is not used, the behaviour is correct.

I still dont understand if there is a bug with the PD_APP_MODAL implementation but the solution seems OK to me & doesnt feel like a workaround.

Here is my working code.

```
import wx
import time

class Application(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.filename = "ModelManager.py"

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(1050, 580))
        self.Show()

        self.progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Update", "Updating SVN Folders...", style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE, maximum=100)
        for ctr in range (5):
            self.progress_dlg.Update(ctr+1, "SVN Updating:...")
            time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(3)
        self.progress_dlg.Update(100)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = Application(None, "SVN Update")
app.MainLoop()
```

The other thread can be found here.
https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/wxpython-app-frame-goes-to-background-after-progressdialog-is-closed/36022

Comment: I noticed that you aren't specifying  `parent=self`, which may explain why it disappears down the window order and selects the pycharm window instead. Could you test with `parent=self` and `Destroy()` and with or without `self.Focus()`. Also try from the command line, rather than from within your IDE.  I'd argue, that given it's related to the window Z-order it's an OS dependant issue.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony you are right `parent=self´ works.
Actually it is better, because without ´wx.PD_APP_MODAL´ it is possible to click back to the application & lose the ProgressDialog() behind it.

with ´parent=self´ the dialog always stays on top.

It seems a it illogical to me though, as I would assume that the main window should be the parent of the ProgressDialog ?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony ah, actually the "self" refers to the Application class rather than the ProgressDialog itself I guess..

Comment: When you `call` the dialog, the current class is `self`. The `parent` option allows you to tell the dialog who the parent is or indeed `None` i.e. an orphan. Using `print(self.progress_dlg.GetParent())` will provide proof.

Comment: The latest comments on the DiscussWxPython thread seem to indicate the problem comes from the default `parent=none` argument & recommend as a solution to define `parent=self` as you suggest. I've tried this in all my applications and it seems to work fine. I'm going to test it this week on the different target PCs before I commit it as a final solution.